# Emulating a different user role

Tags: magento-1.8, user-roles, environment-emulation

Is it possible to emulate a different user role in code?

I'm wondering if it is possible to do something similar to `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail()` where a different store is emulated i.e.:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);
...
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo).
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about your question please ? For instance, what is the reason why you want to emulate a user role ?

Comment: Hi Raphael, we're having issues logging tickets on Zendesk programmatically, and I wanted to emulate an admin user in place of a normal user logging the ticket to test if it was a permissions issue. Obviously the easier and simpler way to do it is to just assign admin rights to the user account I am testing with, but I was curious to know if it were possible to emulate an admin user :)